# Getting Error In Journal Entry Quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to add a journal entry. But it returns like an error

```
Uncaught IdsException: [0]: 2014-01-29 08:13:07 - D:\DummyApps\v3-php-sdk-2.0.1\v3-php-sdk-2.0.1\DataService\DataService.php - 341 - CheckNullResponseAndThrowException - 
Response Null or Empty thrown in D:\DummyApps\v3-php-sdk-2.0.1\v3-php-sdk-2.0.1\Core\CoreHelper.php on line 95'
```

I am using QuickBooks PHP SDK. My code is below:

```
    // Prep Data Services
    $dataService = new DataService($serviceContext);
    if (!$dataService)
    exit("Problem while initializing DataService.\n");

    $linedet = new IPPJournalEntryLineDetail();
    $linedet->PostingType = 'Credit';
    $linedet->AccountRef  = 9;

   $line = new IPPLine();
   $line->Id = 0;
   $line->Description = 'test journal';
   $line->Amount = 2.00;
   $line->DetailType= 'test ';
   $line->JournalEntryLineDetail = $linedet;

   $linedet2 = new IPPJournalEntryLineDetail();

   $linedet2->PostingType = 'Debit';
   $linedet2->AccountRef  = 9;
   $line2 = new IPPLine();
   $line2->Id = 1;
   $line2->Description = 'test journal';
   $line2->Amount = 2.00;
   $line2->DetailType= 'test ';
   $line2->JournalEntryLineDetail = $linedet2;

   // Add a journal
   $journalObj = new IPPJournalEntry();
   $journalObj->SyncToken = '1';
   $journalObj->DocNumber = '1';
   $journalObj->TxnDate = '2014-12-30';
   $journalObj->RefNumber = 't123';
   $journalObj->PrivateNote = 'Just testing';
   $journalObj->Line = array($line, $line2);
   $journalObj->Adjustment  = TRUE;
   $journalObj->IsAdjustment  = TRUE;   
   $resultingObj = $dataService->Add($journalObj );
```

Please help me....I am stuck here.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please set the logger to debug and and check the request and response XMLs. To debug this issue you can try the request XML with APIExplorer first. 
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO
Thanks

Comment: Is there any chance to get back the correct error message and error code from response instead of this useless exception? It is hard to handle the error in the application without knowing the roots of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error here.

The 'DetailType' in the line object must have 'JournalEntryLineDetail'